# To install Haskell in OSX >= 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew, install

GCC was apparently removed from the current Xcode, [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Mac_OS_X#Mac_OS_X_10.9_.28Mavericks.29.2C_Mac_OS_X_10.8_.28Mountain_Lion.29_and_Xcode_5). 
I would like to find a standard way to install Haskell to OSX. 
Not a custom way.

Brew's packages

- haskell-stack
- homebrew/emacs/haskell-mode       Caskroom/cask/haskell-platform

Cabal may be one solution.

How can you install Haskell in OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Haskell Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#the-haskell-tool-stack) is a good option as well. For marketing purposes: Features include automatic installation of packages and separately installed and isolated GHC. Installable from Homebrew with `brew install haskell-stack`.

Answer (score 1):

Package managers like home-brew and macports will provide Haskell

There are separate Haskell releases

There are various ones in the App Store (found by google so I may have missed some)

- [Haskell for Mac](http://haskellformac.com) in the App Store - for £15 -includes and IDE
- [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) - Open Source also available for Windows and Linux - there is an old version in macports